# Undefined symbol after sourcing ros

Tags: ubuntu, python, libraries

I generate a python library using setuptools. The library and the import in python file works fine in my example.

I also had  to use  ros, so before using my python example I run:

```
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh
```

After that command if I run again my example, it told my that my library symbol is missing. But the symbol is well inside the library file.

How could it come from?

Comment: Please update this question to include the exact error message, and exactly what commands you're running to trigger it.